# Update HTTP GET Request from Select Menu Change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a search results page in a PHP site that returns a list of results. I now need to add a filter option to the search results page so that users can further refine the search result from some Select menu choices. The URL for the search results looks like this:

```
findProducts.php?action=searchAssets&orderNumber=xxxx&productName=zzz
```

and is performed from a GET request on the search form page.

I've added some filters using select menus like this:

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Filter By</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="filter" action="filter.php" method="get" role="form">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="filterSearch">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <select class="form-control" name="productType" id="productType">

                <option selected="selected">By Product Type</option>
                                                          <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
                                                            <option value="Trains">Trains</option>
                                                            <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
                              
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I now need to happen, and not sure about how to do this, is that when the Select menu is modified that it performs the search again, e.g. the GET request would now be something like this:

```
findProducts.php?action=searchAssets&orderNumber=xxxx&productName=zzz&productType=Cars
```

if the user selected the Cars option from the select menu. I'm using PHP and Bootstrap so jQuery/PHP solutions can be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a on-chage event to your dropdown, then when triggered append it's value to the current url, and reload the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#productType').change(function(){
        window.location.href = window.location.href + '&productType=' + $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error in the console: 
Left hand side of operator '=' must be a reference.
for the third line in your script (window.location.href = window.location.href + '&productType=' = $(this).val();)

Comment: sorry I typed ".. = $(this).val()'", where it should be "... + $(this).val();". Updated my answer, can you try again?

Answer (score 1):

this is what you need https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

you can do even chained dropdowns. if you want to send more one param (to do WHERE something='a' AND b='c') to that php page use hidden form feilds and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Onn select "change" event, you can call a function which would do a ajax call to your search result url.. like this:

$("#productType").on('change', function(){

```
var product_type = $(this).val(); //selected product type
var your_search_url = "path/to/findProducts.php?action=searchAssets&orderNumber=xxxx&productName=zzz&productType="+product_type;
$.get(your_search_url, function(data, status){  
   // your code here to deal with the search results
});
```

});